# If cell was touched, enable a different cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

At the moment I am using a UITableView with one cell disabled. However I would like to know how I could enable this cell, when another cell is clicked.

Comment: and we just want to know, what u tried so far.

Comment: It may do you good to write in the present tense. Also, have you got any existing code to show us?

Comment: Are you talking about a UITableView?  If so you should be able to calculate the NSIndexPath of the row you want to update from your data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iPad/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html and read it carefully all the info you need is here.

Comment: No its not. It doesn't say anything about enabling and disabling cells.